# Hacer una tabla nueva al saltar de mes en bucle por fechas

Tags: php, bucles, table

Tengo este script:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th colspan=8>".$usuario['Nombre']."</th></tr>";
for($i = $fechini; $i <= $fechafin; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='color:gray;'>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$i)))."</td>";
        echo "<td>cosa</td><td>hola</td><td>adios</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Lo que hace es entre dos fechas me saca un listado de días que tiene el mes, pero estoy intentando hacer que cuando pase de mes cree una nueva tabla. Estoy totalmente perdido de como puedo hacerlo.

Como sacar el mes dentro del bucle si se hacerlo, pero no se me ocurre como hacer la condición para ir saltando de mes a mes dentro del bucle.

A ver si alguien con mas experiencia me da una pista para tirar por ahí.

Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer una validación previa si el mes inicial es diferente al mes final y con ello maquetas una u otra opción.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
  $fechaIni = '2023-01-28';
  $fechaFin = '2023-03-02';
  $anio = explode('-', $fechaIni)[0];
  $mesInicial = explode('-', $fechaIni)[1];
  $mesFinal = explode('-', $fechaFin)[1];
  $diaInicial = explode('-', $fechaIni)[2];
  $diaFinal = explode('-', $fechaFin)[2];

  #Si el mes inicial es igual al mes final, se maqueta una sola tabla
  if($mesInicial == $mesFinal) {
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><th colspan=8>".$usuario['Nombre']."</th></tr>";
    for($i = $fechaIni; $i <= $fechaFin; $i++) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td style='color:gray;'>".$anio."-".$mesInicial."-".$i."</td>";
        echo "<td>cosa</td><td>hola</td><td>adios</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else {
      #En caso de que los meses sean diferentes, se itera sobre el número de meses 
      #para obtener una tabla por cada mes
      for($mes = $mesInicial; $mes <= $mesFinal; $mes++){
        #Consultar la cantidad de días del mes
        #en caso de que haya diferencia de mas de dos meses
        $diasDelMes = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $anio);
        #Si el mes que se está iterando es igual al mes inicial, 
        #se asigna el día inicial, sino se inicia en 1
        $diaMinimo = $mes == $mesInicial ? $diaInicial : 1;
        #Si el mes que se está iterando es igual al mes final, 
        #se asigna el día final, sino se finaliza el ultimo día del mes
        $diaMaximo = $mes == $mesFinal ? $diaFinal : $diasDelMes;
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><th colspan=8>".$usuario['Nombre']."</th></tr>";
        #iterar desde el día mínimo hasta el día máximo
        for($dia = $diaMinimo; $dia <= $diaMaximo; $dia++) {
          echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='color:gray;'>".$anio."-".$mes."-".$dia."</td>";
            echo "<td>cosa</td><td>hola</td><td>adios</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<hr>";
     }
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

La salida del ejemplo, sería algo como esto:

```
2023-01-28  cosa    hola    adios
2023-01-29  cosa    hola    adios
2023-01-30  cosa    hola    adios
2023-01-31  cosa    hola    adios
______________________________________
2023-2-1    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-2    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-3    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-4    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-5    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-6    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-7    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-8    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-9    cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-10   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-11   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-12   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-13   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-14   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-15   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-16   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-17   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-18   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-19   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-20   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-21   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-22   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-23   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-24   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-25   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-26   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-27   cosa    hola    adios
2023-2-28   cosa    hola    adios
_____________________________________
2023-3-1    cosa    hola    adios
2023-3-2    cosa    hola    adios
```

Se complica un poco si cambia el año, pero la lógica sería similar.

Puedes usar funciones para simplificar un poco el código que te dejo de ejemplo, pero es tu decisión. Lo importante es comprender cómo funciona.

Comment: Me gusta la idea  aunque no entiendo muy bien para que necesito comprobar si el mes inicial es igual que el final. Estuve dandole vueltas a hacer el bucle usando days in cal pero no lo use porque no tenia claro como hacerlo de un modo optimo . Voy a probar con tu diseño a ver que tal responde (que son varias consultas a mysql y con el mio va un poco lento ).

Comment: la comprobación del mes es precisamente para hacer el cambio de tablas que mencionas. Si el mes es igual, simplemente se requiere maquetar una tabla, en caso contrario se maqueta una tabla por mes con la cantidad de días del mes o con la cantidad de días que pasas como parámetro. Prueba este código con diferentes fechas y notarás la razón de la comprobación de mes y la consulta de días del mes. En caso de que sigas sin comprender, me cuentas y trato de ser un poco más claro.

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haría así, crearás una tabla vacia al inico del todo, pero la ocultas con css y a correr.

```
$ultimoMes='';
echo '<table class="oculto">';
for($i = $fechini; $i <= $fechafin; $i = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i ."+ 1 days"))) {
   $mesActual=date("m", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$i)));
   if($mesActual!=$ultimoMes){
      $ultimoMes=$mesActual;
      echo "</table><table>";
      echo "<tr><th colspan=8>".$usuario['Nombre']."</th></tr>";
   }
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td style='color:gray;'>".date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$i)))."</td>";
   echo "<td>cosa</td><td>hola</td><td>adios</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Pero eso no me da ningún bucle al saltar el mes

Comment: no termino de entender a que te refieres con crear un bucle al saltar el més.
Esto cerrrará la tabla y abrirá una tabla nueva cada vez que detecte que el mes ha cambiado, no necesitas mil bucles, solo el de los resultados y alguna forma de detectar cuando cambias de més

Comment: ya tienes un bucle para cada día, en el ya puedes detectar si el mes ha cambiado para hacer cosas, o la semana, o el horóscopo... no hace falta un bucle para cada cosa, solo un punto de corte dentro de un bucle general